# Strange black borders in 9 patch file - android

Tags: java, android, png, scale, nine-patch

I'm trying to create a 9 patch file but whenever I edit the png file and add some black lines to it, these black lines are also visible in my app. I thought they are only visible inside the program(draw9patch).

Here is a [screenshot of my image inside the program](http://i.gyazo.com/a61d30c8faab296eb0c8a7b2eaf5ed1e.png):

And here is a [screenshot of my image outside the program(after edit has done)](http://i.gyazo.com/80a81c26136435df5a5b315e8f24c2ef.png) :

Moreover, the image( the 9 patch file ) isn't scaled nicely. Here is a [screenshot of that:](http://i.gyazo.com/8fdf6a5881d9e6df1486b98f8d851348.png)

What's wrong?

Comment: please see how to make 9patches : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: I have already read this guide. It says nothing about my problem.

Comment: Try to put single pixel patch on top and left side.

Comment: the lines at the top and left should not be here, there should only be points where the resize will start

Comment: Make sure **all** the four border of the 9 patch file is correctly made following the introduction.

Comment: name it not foo.png but foo.9.png

Comment: **1** your lower border is WRONG. It must be on the bottom. **2** Name your file `any_name.9.png` (mind the **.9**)

Answer (score 1):

Top and Left : represent stretchable area.

Bottom and Right : represent drawable area.

Check this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 0):

I created 9 patch images and had same black line problem.
My mistake was I rename result image before pasting in res folder. So android didn't recognise that image as 9 patch.

Don't rename result image then you will get proper display in app.

Example: **xxxxx.9.png** (you can rename **xxxxx** content only)

Use as @drawable/**xxxxx** in layout xml.

Thanks!